# MongoDB Check number of connections to specific database

Tags: mongodb, database

Is there a way to check specific connections to a MongoDB database? I know you can use db.serverStatus() to check total connections to the instance, but is there a way to see it on a database level?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there are no facilities to get all the connections (active / inactive) in MongoDB. There are interfaces to know the currently running operations i.e. db.currentOp() - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/, however that is not all the current clients connections.